# Scaling Issue in Visual Studio

Tags: windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I freshly installed visual studio 2013 and started designing my app on XAML, but I am facing one problem.

Earlier when I used to design apps, I used to have a 480x800 area to work with but in this installation, I only have 400 x 640.

What I mean is that if

```
<Grid Height="800">
some code
</Grid>
```

Then it goes out of the screen but if I do like this

```
<Grid Height="640">
some code
</Grid>
```

Then it fits. How to change this?

Comment: Why don't you use `Height="*"` instead of hard coding the height?

Comment: @Anuraj actually i am used to that 480 x 800. I might use it or i may not. But i want to know how to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started creating a new `Windows Phone 8.1 XAML` based application & the scaling in the new 8.1 application is not same as that of in `Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight` applications.

If you want to target Windows Phone 8 or 8.1 Silverlight application, that uses the same scaling principles of always having `480 width & 800 or 853 height` then go to `Visual Studio -> New Project -> Store Apps -> Windows Phone Apps -> Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight)`.

Else if you want to target new Windows Phone 8.1 XAML based application then try referencing this tutorials [Building Apps for Windows Phone 8.1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i wanted to know